# Java: Possible to replace TableModel in an existing JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Is it possible to replace the entire TableModel in an existing JTable or do I have to recreate the JTable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set a new model using the `JTable.setModel()` method

Check the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setModel(javax.swing.table.TableModel)) for details

Comment: Damn - I was using the inline javadoc in the eclipse editor and I missed it, but I went back and checked and it's there.

Comment: Very helpful in the case of a JXTreeTable as well, where you might have to use `setTreeTableModel()`.

Answer (score 5):

When you change the model you are stuck with old column titles.  `getColumnName()` only gets called on initialization.

Comment: so it is not possible to change the column names as well? In my case, I want to make a data viewer table, it gets initialized without data and filled once a different thread provides the model. But, as you said, column names are not appearing!